# Why does a FUTURE grant in Snowflake require AccountAdmin by default?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've set up the following scenario:

The Demo_DB is owned by the sysadmin role. The Demo_Schema was created and is owned by Demo_Developer role. All the objects in Demo_Schema are owned and have been created by the Demo_Developer role.

AccountAdmin created a new role called Demo_Analyst, which the intent is to set up as a read-only user of the Demo_Schema tables. Demo_Developer successfully executed the following grant (assuming because it is the owner of all the tables in the Demo_Schema):

```
use role Demo_Developer; 
grant select on all tables in schema Demo_DB.Demo_Schema to role Demo_Analyst;
```

However, neither Demo_Developer or event SysAdmin (which belongs to the Demo_Developer role) can execute the following:

```
use role sysadmin;
grant select on FUTURE tables in schema Demo_DB.Demo_Schema to role Demo_Analyst;
```

However, the above will execute using the AccountAdmin role. This seemed strange to me at first, but then I reasoned that maybe we won't know which future tables will be created by which owners, so we need an AccountAdmin to grant FUTURE. Is that correct?

I did some more testing and changed ownership of one of the tables in Demo_Schema to a completely different role that Demo_Developer isn't a part of. Then I tried to grant select on all tables using that Demo_Developer again (first statement above), and this time it didn't grant to all tables, but just to the tables Demo_Developer was the owner of.

So I wonder why the attempted grant on FUTURE tables doesn't work the same way - i.e. grant select on future tables owned by the grantor of the future grant.

So my question is: Why do I need an AccountAdmin to grant select on Future tables, but I can use the owner role (Demo_Developer) to grant select on all current tables?

Answer (score 2):

Did you see this in the usage notes?

The MANAGE GRANTS global privilege is required to grant or revoke privileges on future objects at the database level. By default, only the SECURITYADMIN and ACCOUNTADMIN roles have the MANAGE GRANTS privilege.

Comment: I thought I was creating a FUTURE grant at the schema level, not the database level.

Comment: Looking at MANAGE GRANTS a little closer: MANAGE GRANTS: Grants ability to grant or revoke privileges on any object as if the invoking role were the owner of the object. So it makes sense why SECURITYADMIN and ACCOUNTADMIN can grant futures on whatever. But since Demo_Developer owns the schema and the objects, and since I was doing a future grant on the schema (not the database), I thought I'd be able to do it.